# CSS: Menu Items on bottom

Tags: html, css

I want to create a menu where the menu items should be placed on the bottom. Even if they have 2 lines or more.

```css
    ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: #333;
    }

    li {
        float: left;
        height: 90px;
        width: 100px;
    }

    li a {
        display: block;
        color: yellow;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 14px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
        position: relative;
        bottom: -40px;
    }

    li a:hover {
        background-color: #111;
    }
```

```html
    <ul>
      <li><a href="default.asp">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="news.asp">Newsletter & Extras</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.asp">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="about.asp">About</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Right now I try to achieve this with making the a-tags relative and adjust the bottom. but that doesnt work.

so how is that possible, that all texts are aligned on an imaginary line on the bottom?

Comment: you can also use `display:inline-block` & `vertical-align:bottom` instead of `float:left`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flexbox can do that:

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}
li {
  float: left;
  height: 90px;
  width: 100px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
li a {
  display: block;
  color: yellow;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
}
li a:hover {
  background-color: #111;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="default.asp">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="news.asp">Newsletter & Extras</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="contact.asp">Contact</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="about.asp">About</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

ok, found the solution: the li have to be relative, the a-tags inside have to be absolute:

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
}

li {
    float: left;
    height: 90px;
    width: 100px;
    position: relative;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: yellow;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
}

li a:hover {
    background-color: #111;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
 ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #333;
    display: flex;
    padding-top: 50px;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
li a {
    display: block;
    color: yellow;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
}
li a:hover {
    background-color: grey;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this li class:

```
 li {
        float: left;
        height: 90px;            
    }
```

Just remove width from this class.

Answer (score 0):

**Check this i have changed css few palces might be i sloved your problems**

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
    width:100%;
    display: inline-block; 
    text-align: center;
}

li {
   display: inline-block; 

    width: 100px;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: yellow;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    position: relative;
    padding: 10px;
    top:5px;

}

li a:hover {
    background-color: #111;
}
```

https://fiddle.jshell.net/Rajkumarrana/12fsmyzg/